# Получение фрагмента из view

Tags: android

Возможно ли получить фрагмент из view, которое расположено в этом фрагменте?

Собственно вопрос происходит [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805031/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-view-%d0%b8%d0%b7-dialogfragment). Есть ли решение лучше?

Comment: Собственно вопрос происходит отсюда [ru.stackoverflow.com/Как-вызвать-метод-кастомного-view-из-dialogfragment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805031/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-view-%D0%B8%D0%B7-dialogfragment). Возможно есть решение получше..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно передать фрагмент через `setTag()`:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
        // задаём наш фрагмент в качестве тэга
        view.setTag(this);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Далее где-то в другом месте достаём через `getTag()`:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) view.getTag();
```

---

Или другой вариант через контекст:

```
Activity activity = (Activity) view.getContext();
FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
// или
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("exempleTAG");
```

Comment: Спасибо! Реализовал через контекст

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить контекст, в котором создавалось View.

```
Context ctx = view.getContext();
```

Контекст, если хочется, можно скастить к фрагменту.

Также из контекста можно получить пакет и имя класса.

```
ctx.getPackageName()
ctx.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

Ну либо в одно действие

```
view.getContext().getClass().getName();
```

Comment: Разве фрагмент является потомком контекста? Мне думается этот метод должен вернуть `Activity`.

Comment: @woesss да, действительно. Наверное стоит подумать в сторону `view.getParent()`